# If I connect a computer to a external display, i.e. a projector, is it true that the computer had to do more "work"?

Tags: windows, display, projector

If I connect a computer to a external display, i.e. a projector, is it true that the computer had to do more "work" (calculation or whatever)?

Comment: If you have video going on both sides, then yes.

Comment: vaso does that mean that if i connect my laptop to a bigger monitor, i should turn the laptop's monitor off to make the laptop do less work?

Comment: You should not worry, the difference is negligible unless you are talking about an older laptop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if the external display is larger, or if both displays are active at once. Simply going from a digital signal to an analog signal (e.g. DB-15 VGA) does not stress the CPU since there is dedicated circuitry in the video card for this conversion.

Comment: so does that mean that if i connect my laptop to a bigger monitor, i should turn the laptop's monitor off to make the laptop do less work?

Comment: No. You need to disable the laptop's display completely.